# The origin of "заморить червячка"

Tags: значения, идиомы

**"Заморить червячка"** is an idiom which can be loosely translated as *"to get a bite to eat"*, or *"to have a snack / to have something to eat".*

Which worm does the expression refer to? What is its origin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phrase is French in origin (*"tuer le ver"*) and referred originally to the drinking of alcohol on an empty stomach. This was supposed to quite literally "kill the worm" of the parasitic variety.

Here is a [link](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tuer_le_ver) to the French Wiktionary.